# St_ClosestPoint within St_MakeLine Query problem

Tags: postgis, postgresql, sql

I am currently trying to create the closest point (closest_ports_point_test) on the grid (lng_grid_test) from the original points (ports_point), and to create the line connecting the original and the closest points.

```
CREATE TABLE closest_ports_point_test
AS 
SELECT * 
FROM ST_MakeLine(
    ST_ClosestPoint(ports_point.geom, lng_grid_test.geom),
    ports_point.geom
    );
```

And I also tried :

```
CREATE TABLE closest_ports_point_test
AS 
SELECT * 
FROM ST_MakeLine(
    ST_ClosestPoint(
        lng_grid_test.geom::geometry(LineString, 4326), 
        ports_point.geom::geometry(Point, 4326)
        ), 
    ports_point.geom::geometry(Point, 4326)
    );
```

But I get the following error warning for both results:

> ERREUR:  entrée manquante de la clause FROM pour la table « lng_grid_test »
>   LINE 2: AS SELECT * FROM ST_MakeLine(ST_ClosestPoint(lng_grid_test.g...
>   ********** Error **********
>   ERREUR: entrée manquante de la clause FROM pour la table « lng_grid_test »
>   SQL state: 42P01
>   Character: 310

Do you have any idea about what could be wrong with that?

Comment: I also tried :  CREATE TABLE closest_ports_point_line_test(gid serial, geom geometry(LineString,4326))
AS SELECT * FROM(
SELECT
ST_MakeLine(ST_ClosestPoint(ports_point.geom::geometry(Point,4326), lng_grid_test.geom::geometry(LineString,4326)), ports_point.geom::geometry(Point,4326)) AS close_line
FROM ports_point, lng_grid_test
)AS geom;                                                
But there I get:  
ERREUR:  erreur de syntaxe sur ou près de « AS »
LINE 8: AS SELECT * FROM(

Answer (score 2):

You need to define how the tables included are related.

Also, for this purpose you have st_shortestline, that creates the line for you.

The syntax is:
Select st_shortestline(a.geom, b.geom)
From a, b

Then you probably want to put some where clause there or you will get all possible combinations between the tables.

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure what you're implying by "how the tables inclued are related"...?
  
Even with a simple query like :
SELECT ST_ShortestLine(ports_point.geom, lng_grid_test.geom)
FROM ports_point, lng_grid_test;
  
I get an error (ERREUR:  Operation on mixed SRID geometries)

Comment: And If i try try to set the SRID: SELECT ST_ShortestLine(ports_point.geom::geometry(Point,4326), lng_grid_test.geom::geometry(LineString,4326)) FROM ports_point, lng_grid_test; I get the error : ERROR: Geometry SRID (0) does not match column SRID (4326)

Comment: The syntax geom(geometry,4326) doesn't set the srid.what it does is like adding a constraint on srid 4326 on the geometry. To set the srid use st_setsrid, to change srid use st_transform

Comment: With find_srid I just found out that my table ports_point was SRDI=0, so I think this is the problem, but I thought it would be ok with setting ports_point.geom::geometry(Point,4326) for the ShortestLine clause....?

Comment: Ok I used : ALTER TABLE ports_point 
  ALTER COLUMN geom TYPE geometry(Point, 4326) 
    USING ST_SetSRID(geom,4326); to set my SRID to 4326 for port_points, and it's currently running for the shortestline. Hope it will go well, Thanks :)